# The real-valued function on $C [a, b]$ which sends any function $f$ into $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$ is uniformly continuous. What is $C [a, b]$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

What's the meaning of this $C([a,b])$? What is its distance function? The text doesn't give any explanation. Page 133, introduction to analysis by Maxwell Rosenlicht, Dover Publications, inc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any space $X$, $C(X)$ denotes the set of all continuous functions $X\to\mathbb{R}$ (or $X\to\mathbb{C}$, depending on context).  Such functions form a vector space under pointwise addition and scalar multiplication.  If $X$ is compact, this vector space has a norm given by $\|f\|=\sup\{|f(x)|:x\in X\}$.

So, in this case, $C([a,b])$ is the set of continuous functions $[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$, with metric $d(f,g)=\sup\{|f(x)-g(x)|:x\in[a,b]\}$.

Answer (score 4):

It is the set of all functions $f\colon [a,b] \to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is continuous. This is a Banach space, with norm $\|f\| := \max_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)|$.